# music problems when using pygame + multiprocessing

Tags: python, pygame, multiprocessing

I'm tring to run a *script* that would play music via a process. the code below is a stripped down version of my code but it's good enough to replicate the problem. If I call the `normal()` procedure I hear music so I know the procedure is correct and everything is connected properly, however, if I call `normal()` using multiprocessing there is no sound... It runs `normal()` but still no *audio*...

Any suggestions?
thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# 
# Import required Python libraries
import pygame, time
import multiprocessing as mp
localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
pygame.init()
cs = 0 

def normal( cs ):
# main loop
    try:
        if cs == 1: 
              while cs == 1:
                 print " Starting normal function"   
                 pygame.mixer.music.load('/home/user/scripts/music.mp3')
                 pygame.mixer.music.play()
                 time.sleep(20)
                 pygame.mixer.music.stop()              
              #return;

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Quit" 

try:

  print " Starting music"   
  # play here 
  cs = 1
  p2 = mp.Process(target=normal, args=(cs,))
  p2.start()
  p2.terminate()
 #normal( cs )           

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "  Quit" 
# End script
```

Comment: what is the sample rate of your file?

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for me:
setting multiprocessing start method to spawn.

```
import pygame, time
import multiprocessing as mp
localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
pygame.init()
cs = 0 

def normal( cs ):
# main loop
    try:
        if cs == 1: 
              while cs == 1:
                 print(" Starting normal function")
                 pygame.mixer.music.load('/home/sumit/qt/audio.wav')
                 pygame.mixer.music.play()
                 time.sleep(20)
                 pygame.mixer.music.stop()              
              #return;

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Quit") 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    try:
        mp.set_start_method('spawn')
        print(" Starting music")   
        # play here 
        cs = 1
        p2 = mp.Process(target=normal, args=(cs,))
        p2.start()
        p2.join()
        p2.terminate()
        #normal( cs )           

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Quit") 
    # End script
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('/home/user/scripts/music.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1,0) # add this args
sleep(20) #remove this line
mixer.music.stop() #remove this line
```

Adding `pygame.mixer.music.play(-1,0)` means that the music will play in loop until you quit the game e.g.

Try to remove `sleep(20)` and `mixer.music.stop()`.

Also check if you are playing a `44.1kHz` MP3, the default `22050` frequency works, but a `48kHz` mp3 plays in less than half speed - `48000` or `24000` works then.

Or try this approach depending on sample rate:

```
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/user/scripts/music.mp3').play()
```

Or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649884/play-music-using-pygame-but-no-sound).

Comment: Thanks for trying but it still didn't solve the problem. The function "normal" seems to be working fine if I call it directly, it seems that only when I call it via the multiprocessing there is no audio.. I do see the output of "Starting normal function" when calling it via p2.start()

Comment: @badatz what happens if you `print "here"` after the `pygame.mixer.music.play(-1,0)`?